# Is In its stead a clause?

Tags: grammar, phrases, clauses

I'm paraphrasing my sentences in example but :

I don’t miss an establishment that profits from the poor.
In its stead; I hold fond memories of noun, noun, and noun.

Am I using 'In its stead' correctly? I'm using the *its* part, of the *In its stead* phrase, to refer to the first statement. I dont know if that's correct or coming across as I would like. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a comma or no punctuation. The semicolon is incorrect.

Comment: No, "in its stead" is a preposition phrase, not a clause. Drop the semicolon (a comma is optionally possible). See James K's answer for further info.

Answer (score 2):

"In its stead" is not a clause (there's no verb).  It is a prepositional phrase.

The meaning is similar to "In its place".  You could say "We knocked down the old establishment. In its stead we built a school."  The school was built in the place of the old establishment.  Or you could say.  "The boss is ill.  In her stead, I will be chairing the meeting." You are taking the place of the boss.

You aren't a replacement for the old establishment, so you aren't using the phrase correctly.  You can use some linking phrase like "On the other hand".
or "Nevertheless".

Comment: I don't think any American would ever use that phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's an archaic [idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20someone%27s%2Fsomething%27s%20stead#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20in%20someone%27s%2Fsomething%27s,another%20arose%20in%20its%20stead.).

**Instead** would be most common today.